# What is gzip(gfe) in user agent

Tags: firefox, mobile, mobile-safari, user-agent

I recently see lot of request to my server from browsers with `gzip(gfe)` in user agent. Which browser uses them in user agent. What it actually do. Some examples below:

- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1,**gzip(gfe)**
- Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0,**gzip(gfe)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is gzip(gfe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862874/what-is-gzipgfe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/#parse-useragent decodes it as "via Google Frontend". An [answer to a similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35499089/1026) says

> You will see this token, if a user translate[s] your website in another language with the Google Translator.

...that is when Google makes a request to your site on behalf of the user when [the user uses Google Translate](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534559?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0) to translate your web page. I just tried it and can confirm I see the request with `,gzip(gfe)` in the user agent. The referrer looks like: `https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=es&u=<ORIGINAL URL>`

Comment: How can I replicate this issue. I tried Google translate, but couldn't see gzip in user agent.

Comment: I added a link to the instructions on using Google Translate with web pages. I see a gfe-tagged request after following these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Weird stuff. It's also on youtube. Request:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX
```

where "XXX" is the video ID. Look at the source code:

```
"INNERTUBE_CONTEXT":
{
    "client":
    {
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.1851.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1851.0,gzip(gfe)",
    }
}
```

A POST request goes off to:

```
https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=XXX&prettyPrint=false
```

where "XXX" is some fancy identifier. The POST data replicates the code above.

"gzip" probably means browser supports gzip compression. What's "gfe"?